# Rails error when I try to create a new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to rails and I've been following the RailsTutorial.
I've been able to git push and create 2 other projects and then it goes wrong. Running on OSX Mavericks.

I have a workingfolder called 'workspace'.

When I run ruby -v I get

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
```

When I run rails -v:

```
Rails 4.0.5
```

Then I have tried both:

```
rails new sample_app --skip-test-unit
```

and:

```
rails _4.0.5_ new sample_app --skip-test-unit
```

(that installs and runs fine)

then I do: cd sample_app, this appears:

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/sebastian/workspace/sample_app/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
```

I continue and ask for the ruby -v, and rails-v inside and it's the same. Working fine so far.

Then the tutorial wants me to remove the current gemfile and replace it with this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

once I have updated my gemfile I get this error on rails -v

```
Could not find gem 'rails_12factor (= 0.0.2) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

the tutorial wants me to

```
$bundle install --without production
$ bundle update
$ bundle install
```

if I do bundle install --without production
I get this error:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

with this stuff on top:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwA4q.png

so how do I fix this? What am I doing wrong. Would be good with a very noobie friendly answer.

Comment: libiconv is missing, try to `brew install libiconv` in your terminal

Comment: And probably `brew install libxml2`, also ignore @Thahakp comment, it's useless.

Comment: I'm beginning to think Nokogiri failing to install is just part of the standard install process.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Gemfile lists rails_12factor (the number twelve, not letter L then 2. Simply changing this fixed it for me:

group :production do
    gem 'pg',               '0.17.1'
    gem 'rails_12factor',   '0.0.2'
end

Following the same tutorial, I guess.